# Font size while designing a web template in photoshop at size 1280px by 1000px

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I am fairly new to designing and almost self taught, so please excuse me if my question is downright stupid.

I have found that when I design a web page in photoshop, my font size is very small and unreadable unless the document is zoomed up at 100%. But if I look at other people's work, their fonts are readable even at 66.67% zoom level or even lower.

Is there a standard for web page design in photoshop for fonts? How should I tackle this problem?

Just to add, I had the same problem even while designing phone apps, until someone on behance commented and suggested that "if you use photohsop to make mockups, try seeing the mockups at 50% size...thats about the size that you will see on a phone screen". This pretty much solved the problem.

Any such suggestions for designing web pages in photoshop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, there isn't a "perfect" size for text, since it completly depends on design. I use 16-18px for the body text, 30px for h2 and 48px for h1. The rest you will have to adapt for your own design.

Try that and see how you go :)

Comment: Also, the size is relative to the font itself as they don't all display in a normative pattern.

Comment: Thank you Ross and Aibrean for your inputs. As a general rule, after looking at various designs from other awesome designers, I found out that it should be fairly readable at 66.67% zoom level in photoshop. Although you guys are right too, it depends.